# Passing 'axios' to 'Swiper' with Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, swiper.js

I am working on a simple carousel which uses data fetched using axios. I have it working in a different way (not using virtual slides) but due to the amount of images/urls being fetched I would like to pass it as virtual data. How do I pass the data fetched by axios into 'Vue Awesome Swiper'.

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide"
        v-for="(slide, index) in virtualData.slides"
        :key="index"
        :style="{left: `${virtualData.offset}px`}"
      >{{slide}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and

```
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        slides: (function () {
          var slides = [];
          return slides;
        }()),
        // virtual data
        virtualData: {
          slides: [],
        },
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      const self = this;
      const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        virtual: {
          slides: self.slides,
          renderExternal(data) {
            self.virtualData = data;
          },
        },
      });
      // axios
      var resquest = URL to API | JSON 
      axios
       .get(request)
       .then(response => {
         this.slides = response.data.data.Gallery.GalleryImage.link;
       })
    },
  };
```

Vue noob here.